# I’m looking for a concrete material for skimming over existing concrete 1.5” thick to 1/8”

Tags: self-leveling-concrete

I’m looking to fix my side walk. The slabs are 8’ long. I want to lay a new material over top to make
It look like new concrete

Comment: If adding new concrete, you will want at least 1.5 inch thick for it to last.  Any thinner you are probably looking at pressure washing or paint.

Comment: Maybe some kind of epoxy resin impregnated with grit (for traction).  No concrete material will stick.  Also, I'm surprised 1.5" thick concrete hasn't already shattered.

Comment: @Huesmann pretty sure the "range of thickness of new coating" is desired to be from 1.5" to 1/8" - implying that the sidewalk iss quite unlevel -  and I agree with crip659 that the thin end is too thin to hold up. Most epoxies are not good in the sunlight, unless coated with something else to block the UV.

Comment: Not enough information in the question, but if just needing to it to look nicer/newer then pressure washing is the best bet.  If the need is for fixing/repair/levelling, Then usually the best way is for removing of the old cement, preparing/improving of the base and then new cement pour.  Editing more information of what exactly you need into the question will get a good answer.

Comment: Yup, [edit] and add pictures usually helps. And if the sidewalk is that far out of whack, it will probably go out of whack again even if you could find a miracle cure for the surface (which I don't think you will.) The better-quality sidewalk locally was done with sliding reinforcement at the joints. They poured every other block, with smooth bars sticking out the ends. Those bars got plastic sleeves before they poured the adjacent block so they could move back and forth but not up and down. The joint was also spaced and filled with a rubber-type sealant after removing the forms and spacers.

Comment: One must also wonder why a contracting company needs to consult a bunch of DIYers about this...